# Reading text files using SQL in R Programming

Tags: r

I have a huge text file with no column headers. I want to read only the first 2 columns and give those columns some names. I would like to incorporate SQL query in read.table syntax.  Is it possible to do it in singe line of syntax?

Comment: No - R doesn't support SQL syntax within R commands. They are different languages.

Comment: What do you mean "incorporate SQL query"? To select columns or include a where clause or join with something else?

Comment: Hi @Spacedman, While importing the text file, I want to read only two columns and also like to use group by on one of the column. Because the data file is so huge >7-8 GB

Comment: Show the first few lines of your CSV, tell us which columns you want, explain what column you are grouping by and how you want to aggregate the data per group variable. Maybe even show some SQL. Edit your question and explain all this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
library(data.table)
fread(file_name, header = FALSE, select = 1:2, 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = c("Field1", "Field2"))
```

you may also want to set the `sep` and `dec` fields depending on the type of file you have.

Check out the documentation `?fread`